# Problems linking mysql database with java based web app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring Data to pull and control data from a mysql database. I have been having problems putting this data into a table. I am using Vaadin and following these tutorials:

https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/modern-web-apps-with-spring-boot-and-vaadin/spring-boot-backend-database-jpa-repositories-services

(but am trying to adapt for my own purposes). The tutorial creates an `AbstractEntity` from which other entities extend. From what I have worked out, this is some form of entity manager which I believe attempts to distinguish unique entities. As I was just attempting to see how all of these objects fit together, I decided to create only one entity and extend it from this `AbstractEntity` named `Stock`. This `Stock` Class is defined as follows:

```
package com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table (name="stock_info")
public class Stock extends AbstractEntity implements Cloneable {
    @Id
    private String Ticker;
    
    private String Region;

    public String getTicker() {
        return Ticker;
    }
    public void setTicker(String ticker) {
        Ticker = ticker;
    }
    
    public String getRegion() {
        return Region;
    }
    public void setRegion(String region) {
        Region = region;
    }
    

}
```

This links to a table in my mysql database named "stock_info", the table has more than two columns but I was only testing, so I decided to only create variables for two of these columns, 'Region' and 'Ticker'. This is just a database with a list of stock tickers and has some information about them, one of the bits of information being the region.

The `AbstractEntity` is defined as follows:

```
package com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
}
```

I also have the following `StockService` Service defined as follows:

```
import com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity.Stock;
import com.stockmachine.v2.backend.repository.StockRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Service 
public class StockService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StockService.class.getName());
    private StockRepository stockRepository;

    public StockService(StockRepository stockRepository) { 
        this.stockRepository = stockRepository;
    }

    public List<Stock> findAll() {
        return stockRepository.findAll();
    }

    public long count() {
        return stockRepository.count();
    }

    public void delete(Stock stock) {
        stockRepository.delete(stock);
    }

    public void save(Stock stock) {
        if (stock == null) { 
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "Contact is null. Are you sure you have connected your form to the application?");
            return;
        }
        stockRepository.save(stock);
    }
}
```

and repository:

```
package com.stockmachine.v2.backend.repository;

import com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity.Stock;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public interface StockRepository extends JpaRepository<Stock, String> {

}
```

And the main view ui is:

```
package com.stockmachine.v2.ui;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity.Stock;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.stockmachine.v2.backend.service.StockService;

@Route("") 
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private StockService stockService;
    private Grid<Stock> grid = new Grid<>(Stock.class); 

    public MainView(StockService stockService) {
        addClassName("list-view"); 
        setSizeFull(); 
        configureGrid(); 
        
        add(grid); 
        updateList();
    }
   

  private void configureGrid() {
    grid.addClassName("stock-grid");
    grid.setSizeFull();
    grid.setColumns("ticker","region"); 

   }
  private void updateList() {
      grid.setItems(stockService.findAll());
   }
}
```

From what I understand (may be completely wrong), the main view will create an instance of the service class `StockService` which creates an instance of the `StockRepository` which gets various parameters from the `Stock` class which is linked to the database table referenced with `@Table`.This throws the following errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.stockmachine.v2.ui.MainView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.stockmachine.v2.ui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.stockmachine.v2.backend.service.StockService.findAll()" because "this.stockService" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:294) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.2.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:160) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:135) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:134) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:518) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:498) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:230) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:249) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:220) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:186) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:93) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1526) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:475) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1545) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) ~[flow-server-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.2.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.stockmachine.v2.ui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.stockmachine.v2.backend.service.StockService.findAll()" because "this.stockService" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.stockmachine.v2.backend.service.StockService.findAll()" because "this.stockService" is null
    at com.stockmachine.v2.ui.MainView.updateList(MainView.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.stockmachine.v2.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 76 common frames omitted

2021-01-28 17:22:04.316  INFO 15528 --- [onPool-worker-5] dev-updater                              : No js modules to update 'D:\eclipse\StockMachineV2\target\frontend\generated-flow-imports.js' file
2021-01-28 17:22:49.207 ERROR 15528 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.v.flow.router.InternalServerError      : There was an exception while trying to navigate to ''

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.stockmachine.v2.ui.MainView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.stockmachine.v2.ui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.stockmachine.v2.backend.service.StockService.findAll()" because "this.stockService" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:294) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ...
```

I assume `this.stockService is null` means that the service is not actually collecting any data from my table and thus returning as null. I am not sure if this has something to do with me removing the entity managers functionality. I assume it is just a problem with the service, but I cannot work it out.

I'm not expecting anyone to debug my code considering how much there is, but perhaps if possible, explain to me how all of these resources communicate such that I may be able to debug myself, as I have not been able to find a clear detailed explanation online.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Way too much code!!! [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _but am trying to adapt for my own purposes_ Complete the tutorial. Learn what it is teaching...THEN adapt things to your own purposes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have completed the database management parts of the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that Stock was defining two ids (id form AbstractEntity and Ticker) and is not implementing Serializable.

For the second issue...just add this.stockService = stockService in MainView constructor

Comment: I am not sure if you will see this, but could you explain to me what the id tag does in the AbstractEntity class, as I have decided to remove the tag from ticker in the Stock class and changed id to Ticker in the AbstractEntity, assuming that it would now take the role of the intitial id, but it seems to be causing more problems

Comment: Is a JPA annotation to define the object field that will be used as primary key in the database table